# Onclick in HTML with custom language

Tags: javascript, html

I've made my own minimal language similar to Javascript, and have it functioning in an html file. I have my my-lang code (I'll call the language "my-lang") in between script tags, with the script type property set to "my-lang". Another JS file reads all the code in my-lang, then runs it. Say I had an anchor tag like this:

`<a onclick="someJSfunction();">Text text text</a>`

In the onclick property it runs some JS code. I want it to run code in my-lang. I had a few ideas, but none of them are ideal. Here are a few:

1. In my JS parser which is at the bottom of the HTML file, I have a function that just runs code in my-lang, like a my-lang eval() written in JavaScript. Then in HTML, you can do `<a onclick='run_my_lang("code in my-lang as a string")'>Text text text</a>`
2. I saw a bunch of devs prefacing the onclick text with a label "javascript:". I thought that was for something else, but I'm not sure. I dont know if this will work, but maybe something like `onclick="my-lang:code"`

Any ideas on how to do this without the prefixes?

In my-lang I have event handlers working, I just would also like to be able to do it in line.

Comment: first one   (damn that rule of 15 signs min in comment ^_^).

Comment: @2oppin Why? I've been doing that so far but it's not ideal since the people writing in my-lang will have to run a javascript function to run my-lang code. That doesn't make any sense, plus, it adds an extra set of quotes, which makes things harder since if they have any quotes in the my-lang code, they'll have to escape some quotes. Is there some setting, maybe a meta-tag they can use to change the programming language?

Comment: now I hit the max limit) so put it to an answer, hope it helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As I wrote in the comment, the solution would be the **1st** (onclick='run_my_lang("code")') if you already can do it than it's totally cool, really.

   If you are able to process on-click then your lang should be **run on
   client** (so in a browser), and the only lang available in browser is
   JS.

(You can't enforce Chrome or Safari to process construction "my-lang:code").

2. If you can solve it via **2nd** option, then it means you should have a some compiler that would translate your **template** with "my-lang: code" into "javascript: code" or "run_my_lang('code')", so you still will need to implement 1st.
3. Oh, ok you have no need to use "my-lang" in Chrome|FF|Safari|Whatever, you have your own "WhateverBrowser" that can process "my-lang: code" *(alongside with [HTML](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all), [CSS](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all) and bunch of other things (and not to forget same Javascript))* in the received from the server HTML, and maybe your "WhateverBrowser" even written in "my-lang", that would be cool (but I doubt you have "WhateverBrowser" or ready to compete with Chrome|FF|Safari|Whatever)

   Or (maybe) you would have some **specific "browser"** that browse specific pages, can process mouse events and pass it to your lang.

And now to the main point, **what is "my-lang"**?

Unless it's 3rd (specific browser) your lang in one or another way is written in JS, so in the end it's JS lib:

```js
window.myLang = function(code) {
       let [,func,arg] = code.match(/^myLang:([a-zA-Z]+)\((.*)?\)$/);
       if (myLangFunctions[func])
          myLangFunctions[func](arg);
       return this;
    };
let myLangFunctions = {
    sound: (arg) => {
        switch(arg) {
            case 'dog': alert('bark-bark');break;
            case 'cat': alert('meow-meow');break;
            case 'frog': alert('kero-kero');break;
            default: alert('u-u-u-u-u');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: double 3px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myLang('myLang:sound(dog)')">dog</div>
<div onclick="myLang('myLang:sound(cat)')">cat</div>
<div onclick="myLang('myLang:sound(frog)')">frog</div>
<div onclick="myLang('myLang:sound(whatever)')">whatever</div>
```

And to solve it via 2nd option you will just need pre-compiler that will translate your template into some JS or HTML code (like [JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#JSX)), so it would be just an extension of your 1st solution.

PS: I really think that your question purely theoretical, or even (maybe) one of your probable questions on some exams, but still wrote it for fun )) and hope it helps to you in your future path :)

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! And it's not purely hypothetical. Theres a couple other questions I asked here about it, and it is in development. I don't have my own browser. I guess I'll go ahead with the function route then. By the way, this is a small piece of a larger project. I'm not just making a bad alternative of JS.